# The server throws an exception instead of displaying "database does not exist"

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I am using OpenERP 7 on ubuntu 12.04. I started the server with "list_db = False". It works fine : the menu list was changed by an input field. But when I write a name of database which does not exit, the server throws an exception instead of displaying a message : "database does not exit" for example. This is the text of the exception:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)

   File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 867, in authenticate
    req.session.authenticate(db, login, password, env)

   File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 115, in authenticate
    uid = self.proxy('common').authenticate(db, login, password, env)

  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)

  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)

Server Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 433, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 444, in exp_authenticate
    res_users = pooler.get_pool(db).get('res.users')

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
    return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 192, in get
    update_module)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 208, in new
    registry = Registry(db_name)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 76, in __init__
    cr = self.db.cursor()

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 484, in cursor
    return Cursor(self._pool, self.dbname, serialized=serialized)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn(dbname))

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 377, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 440, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

OperationalError: FATAL:  database "db_test" does not exist
```

**EDIT:**

I have just located the cause of this bug . Please go to "`web/addons/web/static/src/js/chrome.js: line 706` : you will see that the `on_submit` function has one " `if` " block to verify that the field of the database is not empty. The solution is to add a second " `if` " block to verify if the name entered is in the list of databases before calling the `do_login(db, login, password)` function.

Unfortunately I don't know JavaScript programming to fix that issue

Comment: and who is supposed to be able to read that? Please format it in a readable way.

Comment: ok, I edited it, have fun [glglgl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl) ;)

Comment: I hope you solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

In order to just display the message instead of the whole exception, you can wrap the outermost call in a `try`/`except` block:

```
try:
    <make your call>
except OperationalError, e:
    <evaluate e which is your exception>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, I already know how to use the try/except block. But this bug concerns OpenERP professionals users, in the version 6 of OpenERP, it works fine and the server shows "database does not exit" as a message if the database does not exist( [see this](http://openerp-team.blogspot.com/2009/11/hiding-database-name-on-login.html) ) but in version 7 it throws those exceptions